# Chrome decryption password for Cookies?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies is protected with a password. I need to access this file to try to retrieve login details contained in an old cookie for an account I've lost.

I've seen various guides on how to decrypt sqlite databases generally, but what would the specific instructions me to decrypt the Chrome cookies file? This is for Windows 10, latest Chrome build 57.